# What is a clean way of merging inner arrays into one from map?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, foreach

I've currently got the following below, is there a neater way of doing this without the `forEach`?

It's a Friday and my head has gone to mash today :)

```js
let productsObject = [{
  id: 1,
  addons: [{
    id: 1,
    group_id: 1
  }, {
    id: 2,
    group_id: 1
  }, {
    id: 3,
    group_id: 1
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  addons: [{
    id: 1,
    group_id: 2
  }, {
    id: 3,
    group_id: 2
  }]
}];

let addonsList = [];

productsObject.map(e => e.addons).forEach(e => { 
  addonsList = [...addonsList, ...e];
});

console.log(addonsList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for a one-liner solution:

```js
let productsObject = [{
  id: 1,
  addons: [{
    id: 1,
    group_id: 1
  }, {
    id: 2,
    group_id: 1
  }, {
    id: 3,
    group_id: 1
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  addons: [{
    id: 1,
    group_id: 2
  }, {
    id: 3,
    group_id: 2
  }]
}];

const addonsList = productsObject.reduce((acc, { addons }) => [...acc, ...addons], []);

console.log(addonsList);
```

Comment: Omg this is exactly what I wanted :) - I've been racking my head all morning. I keep forgetting about reduce.

Comment: Glad it helped  yes this function is often a good way to go when transforming arrays

Answer (score 2):

Another good option is to use a [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). Which as the name suggests is a combination of the [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) methods.

```js
let productsObject = [{
  id: 1,
  addons: [{
    id: 1,
    group_id: 1
  }, {
    id: 2,
    group_id: 1
  }, {
    id: 3,
    group_id: 1
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  addons: [{
    id: 1,
    group_id: 2
  }, {
    id: 3,
    group_id: 2
  }]
}];

let addonsList = productsObject.flatMap(e => e.addons);

console.log(addonsList);
```

Comment: Indeed, much simpler 

Comment: Oh this is very neat!, only issue with flatMap we have some customers on `Internet Explorer` still